# How do I resolve this 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, file, http-status-code-403

I have a vhost on a Centos machine (Linux i-8941-35408-VM 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5xen #1 SMP Tue Jul 10 09:29:47 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). My Vhost config file is as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName subdomain.domain.biz
ServerAlias sudomain.domain.biz

DocumentRoot /home/myfolder/public_html/subdomain.domain.biz/public

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /home/myfolder/public_html/subdomain.domain.biz/log/error.log
CustomLog /home/myfolder/public_html/subdomain.domain.biz/log/access.log combined

<Directory /home/myfolder/public_html/subdomain.domain.biz/public>
Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Includes
#What about Multiviews for Options above
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I do not have a .htaccess file.

The directory listing of the "public" folder is as follows

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2763 Jan 22 07:11 FailedTRAN.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11890 Jan 22 18:54 GetHandleRESponse.old
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12024 Jan 23 17:14 GetHandleRESponse.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  9  2012 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2562 Jan 22 07:11 Index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9556 Jan 23 18:21 SendPerformREQuest.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3396 Jan 22 07:11 StatusTRAN.php
```

I am able to access the Index.html from my browser, However any attempt to access GetHandleRESponse.php results in a 403 Forbidden error. So when I send out a request to another server the other server has to post its responses by accessing the GetHandleRESponse.php page. This fails. I am unable to figure out why this is the case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The directories should have the x permission (x doesn't mean execution when we work with dirs, x means access permission).

Comment: Thank you. However the issue was with the Security Context of these files. In SE Linux based flavours like Centos files have a security context. I did a ls -lZ and I got the following listing <br/>    drwxrwxrwx  root root root:object_r:user_home_t SendPerformREQuest.phpso I did a chcon -vR --type=httpd_sys_content_t SendPerformREQuest.php which resolved the issue.